# How to change color on One particular pageBlockSection?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, community, css

I have Change the color using CSS. But i want change the color on one particular pageblocksection. How can i do that. I tried several methods, but does not work. Thanks

```
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Add Batch 3" collapsible="true" columns="1" id="section1">
        <apex:pageBlock >
            //Stuff
        </apex:pageBlcok>
    </apex:pageBlockSection

**CSS**

     html .brandTertiaryBgr {
            background-color:  #1A1A56!important;
            color: #FFFFFF!important;
            font-weight:bold;
            font-size:14px;
            margin-bottom:20px;}
```

By using above css code I would be able to change colours in all my pageblockSections. I used below method to change color, It does not work either`.

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Add Batch 3" collapsible="true" columns="1" id="redSection">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        //Stuff
    </apex:pageBlcok>
<script>colorPageBlock(document.getElementById("{!$Component.redSection}"), "red");</script>
</apex:pageBlockSection
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
function colorPageBlock(pageblock, color) {
if (pageblock != null) pageblock.firstChild.style.cssText = “background-color: ” + color + “;”;

}
</script>
```

Is there any otherway I can Change my pageBlockSection Color? Only for one. Thanks

Comment: As an aside, you rarely need to use JS for static styling.  CSS will do the job, as the solution demonstrates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrapping the `apex:pageBlockSection` in an element that a CSS class can be added to works:

```
<apex:page>

<style>
.custom1 {
    background-color: red !important;
}
.custom3 {
    background-color: green !important;
}
</style>

<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="custom1">
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Section 1">
            Content 1
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel layout="block">
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Section 2">
            Content 2
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="custom3">
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Section 3">
            Content 3
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

producing this output:

[image: Output]

**PS**

To style the headers you can make use of a CSS [descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors):

```
<style>
.custom1 .pbSubheader {
    background-color: red !important;
}
.custom3 .pbSubheader {
    background-color: green !important;
}
</style>
```

where `pbSubheader` is a class applied by the Visualforce framework to the header.

Comment: Thanks. I want to change the color in Pageblocksection Header (Section 1) not the background.

Comment: Apply the CSS to the pbHeader child of the .custom1 element. `.custom1 .pbHeader { /* Your CSS here */ }`

Comment: @Rob I tired using `custom1 .brandTertiaryBgr {background-color:  #1A1A56!important; }` and `custom1 .PbHeader{background-color:  #1A1A56!important; }`. But does not work.

Comment: @danzi You need a dot before the first class name. See the PS.

Comment: @Keith C It works after . before the first class name. Thanks Guys. Appreciate you help.

Comment: I tried to use .custom1.pbSubheader. It did not work. Please help me.